Relation between Survival probability and Credit spread
Let ${CS}_t$ is the term structure of the Credit spread obtained from market.
There is a standard relation between this and and term structure of Survival probability as follows,
${SV}_t = \exp[\left(-CS_t \times t \right) / LGD]$
My question is what is the basis of this formula i.e. how this relationship can be derived?
Thanks for your time.

This formula only holds exactly if both discount rate and intensity are constant and credit spread is paid in continuous time.  Otherwise, it is only an approximation.
To derive it, you write the pricing equation for a CDS:
$(1-R)\int_0^T \lambda exp(-(r+\lambda)u)du = CS\int_0^T  exp(-(r+\lambda)u)du$
and integrate to obtain
$(1-R)\lambda = CS$
The result is sometimes referred to as "credit triangle".

But in the expression which I provided in the original post, there is exp component. How that exp component is coming along?

Survival probability is given by $S(t)=e^{-\lambda t}$. Are you asking why is it so?  This is so only a particular version of a "reduced form" model, where default time is modeled as that of the first jump of a Poisson process.  This is a modelling choice. In a Merton or "structural" model you will have a totally different expression.

Okay. Could you please suggest a good textbook where all these stuffs are discussed in details?

Sure.  Schoenbucher or O'Kane.  The latter author, former Head Credit Quant at Lehman even has a Python library on Git.   Also Lando

If you define $CS_t$ as your spot default spread, then it comes from an actuarial understanding of what your credit spread is. $CS_t / LGD$ is the risk-neutral probability of default over each year in t years. Default is like a company "dying", so it can be interpreted as a type of mortality rate. Your $CS_t$ needs to be adjusted by the reciprocal of your recovery rate (LGD), because recovery rates are baked into CDS spreads. See the answer below if you want to know why recovery rates are baked into spreads:
How to compute the implied probability of default from a CDS spread?
Also check out "Force of Mortality" on Wikipedia for intuition on your survival probability:
The simplest example is when the force of mortality is constant:
$\mu(y) = \lambda$
Then survival is:
$S_x(t) = e^{-\int_{x}^{x+t} \lambda \,dy}=e^{-\lambda t}$
Think of $CS_t / LGD = \lambda$.
